# Uncaught ReferenceError: add is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html

Hola un cordial saludo.

Estoy haciendo un sistema de tienda, iniciandolo.

Coloque un boton que por medio de JavaScript debe de indicarme el precio lo coloque que me mandara el mensaje por la consola.

Resulta que me arroja el mensaje.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: add is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

Codigo HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nerko+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page-nav">
        <h1>Mi tienda</h1>
        <button id="checkout" class="button-checkout" onclick="pay()">Pagar</button>
    </div>
    <div class="page-content">
        <div class="product-container">
            <h3>nombre</h3>
            <img src="imagenes/product-1.jpg" />
            <h1>$50</h1>
            <button class="button-add" onclick="add('product-1', 50)">Agregar</button>
        </div>

        <div class="product-container">
            <h3>nombre</h3>
            <img src="imagenes/product-2.jpg" />
            <h1>$300</h1>
            <button class="button-add" onclick="add('product-2', 300)">Agregar</button>
        </div>

        <div class="product-container">
            <h3>nombre</h3>
            <img src="imagenes/product-3.jpg" />
            <h1>$250</h1>
            <button class="button-add" onclick="add('product-3', 250)">Agregar</button>
        </div>

        <div class="product-container">
            <h3>nombre</h3>
            <img src="imagenes/product-4.jpg" />
            <h1>$200</h1>
            <button class="button-add" onclick="add('product-4', 200)">Agregar</button>
        </div>

        <div class="product-container">
            <h3>nombre</h3>
            <img src="imagenes/product-5.jpg" />
            <h1>$10</h1>
            <button class="button-add" onclick="add('product-5', 10)">Agregar</button>
        </div>

        <div class="product-container">
            <h3>nombre</h3>
            <img src="imagenes/product-6.jpg" />
            <h1>$650</h1>
            <button class="button-add" onclick="add('product-6', 650)">Agregar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Coloque el script.js arriba con el head no funciona y debajo antes de cerrar el body y el html y tampoco funciona

El codiog JS:

```
let products = [];
let total = 0;

function add(product, price) {
    console.log(product, price);
    products.push(product);
    total = total + price;
    document.getElementById("checkout").innerHTML = `Pagar $${total}`
}

function pay() {
    window.alert(products.join(", \n"));
}
```

Codigo bastante sencillo.

Revise si esta leyendo el archivo script.js

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Efectivamente lo lee como es debido.

Comment: Cual es el elemento con el id `checkout`?

Comment: Tienes la etiqueta script al final entre el `body` y `html`?, a mí me funciono perfecto

Comment: @JoseMgz_Ux el elemento checkout es el boton para pagar `<button id="checkout" class="button-checkout" onclick="pay()">Pagar</button>`. la etiqueta de script la coloco dentro del `head` no funciona, la coloco desdepues antes de terminar el `body` y tampoco funciona

Comment: @JoseMgz_Ux veo que al abrirlo haciendo doble click funciona correctamente pero cuando lo cargo por un servidor como apache llamando el `localhost/tienda` me da ese error, tienes idea de porque pasa?

Comment: No está demás recordar: [_Nunca debes usar los atributos HTML de manejador de eventos - son obsoletos, y usarlos es una mala práctica._](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these). Considera usar [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#using_addeventlistener).